# Specifying directory as an input within Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a particular text from a filename using regex and I am able to do so if I pass only one filename as an input. However, I want to do the same for all the filenames in a particular directory. I understand that `re.search` can only accept string as an input? Is there a way to pass the directory as an input?

Below is the code I am using,

```
import os
import sys
import re
firstarg=sys.argv[1]
a = str(firstarg)
m = re.search(r'(?<=T)(.*)(?=\()', os.listdir( a )).group()
print (m)
```

Comment: inevitably with any form of looping

Answer (score 0):

This will print an array of strings that match the regex.
This will run the regex over each file and folder in the directory,
and if any file or folder contains a match, that match is appended to the array 'm'
Note: Not Recursive.

```
import os
import sys
import re

firstarg=sys.argv[1]
a = str(firstarg)
files = os.listdir(a)
m = []

for f in files:
    match = re.search(r'(?<=T)(.*)(?=\()', f)
    if( match != None):
        m.append( match.group() )

print (m)
```

Example:
sys.argv[1] = '/'

File Tree:

- /

  - File_Tvalue1(
  - File_Tvalue2(
  - Folder_Tvalue3(

    - File_Tvalue4(

Result:
['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

If you want it to be Recursive and a function.

```py
import os
import sys
import re
def FindMatchesInDirectory(directory, afterRegex, beforeRegex, recursive=True):
    results = []
    for r, d, f in os.walk(directory):
        for path in f:
            match = re.search(r'(?<='+str(afterRegex)+')(.*)(?='+str(beforeRegex)+')', str(path))
            if( match != None):
                results.append( match.group() )    
        for path in d:
            match = re.search(r'(?<='+str(afterRegex)+')(.*)(?='+str(beforeRegex)+')', str(path))
            if( match != None):
                results.append( match.group() )    
        if ( recursive != True):
            break
    return results
```

Example: Get All matches recursively. Any value Between 'T' and '('

```
print (FindMatchesInDirectory(sys.argv[1], 'T', '\('))
```

Result:
['value3', 'value2', 'value1', 'value4']

Example: Get All matches without recursion

```
print (FindMatchesInDirectory('/', 'T', '\(', False))
```

Result:
['value3', 'value2', 'value1']